# Is that possible to make cast field in fetchxml?

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

Is that possible to make cast field from identifier to string in fetchxml?
I have this query:

```
select *
from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2
on t1.stringId=CAST( t2.id as varchar(40))
where t2.id is null and t1.childid is not null
```

and  this row `t1.stringId=CAST( t2.id as varchar(40))`
can't make in fetchxml while field "stringId" is string but it's value is GUID
and I want to have that equality.

In fetchxml:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" >
  <entity name="table1 " >
    <attribute name="stringid" />
    <attribute name="te_name" />
    <link-entity name="table1" from="id" to="stringid" link-type="outer" alias="s" />
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition entityname="s" attribute="stringid" operator="null" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: surprisingly as Jonas said its working, I copied some record guid into textbox of another entity & tested the join query in xrmtoolbox. :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I am missing something, but Dynamics CRM/365 is quite forgiving when it comes to joining types.
It is quite possible to join a string field to a guid field.
See this sample, where I have placed a guid of an account in the fax attribute of a contact:

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' >
  <entity name='contact' >
    <attribute name='fullname' />
    <attribute name='fax' />
    <attribute name='parentcustomerid' />
    <filter type='and' >
      <condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='0' />
    </filter>
    <attribute name='contactid' />
    <link-entity name='account' from='accountid' to='fax' link-type='outer' >
      <attribute name='name' />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

So yes, you are correct that casting is not possible, but the query in your example still executes nicely, which I guess was the goal of it all.

Comment: it worked Wednesday but yesterday it give Generic sql error

Comment: Interesting... :-/
Generic SQL Error is probably due to an invalid guid in the string field. I get the same when testing using a non-guid.
Feel free to upvote my answer if you agree it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Casting is not possible in fetchxml. (Am unable to test this right away.)

Link entity join the 2 entities on Key GUIDs (Primary & Foreign Keys), it's better to create the relationship to maintain Database design & query them.

Interestingly, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309405.aspx) is saying Id as string in schema:

```
<!--

link-entity element - used for joining one entity to its "parent"

-->
  <!-- [XDR-XSD] "link-entity" element  -->
  <xs:complexType name="FetchLinkEntityType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0"
               maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <!-- -->
      <xs:element ref="all-attributes"
                  minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="attribute"
                  type="FetchAttributeType"
                  minOccurs="0"
                  maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element name="order"
                  type="FetchOrderType"
                  minOccurs="0"
                  maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element ref="filter"
                  minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="link-entity"
                  type="FetchLinkEntityType" />
    </xs:choice>
    <!-- -->
    <xs:attribute name="name"
                  use="required"
                  type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="to"
                  type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="from"
                  type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="alias"
                  type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="link-type"
                  type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="visible"
                  type="xs:boolean"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="intersect"
                  type="xs:boolean"></xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Update:

Natively, fetchxml uses the guid keys to join (ex. From Advanced find). But it seems we can override that `from` and `to` with any field. It’s working as of today, Probably undocumented henceforth unsupported.

Comment: there are any way to get that relation

Comment: @ʚïɞAyaAlaamʚïɞ Create 1:N relationship or Lookup attribute to do that