# Understanding Link-entity in FetchXML

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I understand `<link-entity>` is used to do joins, but can you help me translate the following into english?

```
<entity name = "example">

*insert a bunch of attributes*

     <link-entity name="providercertification" from="providerid" to="vendorid" alias="aa">
```

I understand `<link-entity>` is used for joins, but the join type is not specified, so that is throwing me off. How does the link-entity work if no join type is specified? Is it automatically an inner join?

Also, which column does the from part apply `to`? The very first entity or the one specified in the `<link-entity`>?

Same question for the `from` part.

Comment: Read this: https://dynamicscrmpros.com/microsoft-dynamics-crm-fetchxml-link-entities/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/use-fetchxml-construct-query#create-the-query-string) the below query is totally valid, which means `alias`, `from` & `link-type` are optional.

`from` always refer to same entity as link-entity node (primary key `systemuserid` of `systemuser` in this case). `to` refers to attribute of entity parent node (`owninguser` of `account` in this case)

```
   <entity name='account'>   
      <attribute name='accountid'/>   
      <attribute name='name'/>   
      <link-entity name='systemuser' to='owninguser'>
```

[Use a left outer join in FetchXML to query for records "not in"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/use-left-outer-join-fetchxml-query-records-not-in)

So explicit `link-type='outer'` is required for `outer join` but `inner join` is default.

Interestingly Fetchxml is full of [surprises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48571969/7920473). You can also refer [FetchXML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/fetchxml-schema)