# Left Join fetchXml based on common column

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-365

I have two tables that are not related, but have a common column. I want to join the rows in table B that match with `<attribute name='substitutedproductid'>` in Table A. Table A looks like this:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="productsubstitute">
    <attribute name='substitutedproductid' />
    <attribute name='new_quantity' />
    <attribute name='new_unit' />
    <attribute name='new_grouping' />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="productid" operator="eq" value="{guid}" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Table B looks like this:

```
    <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="new_contractlinedislike">
    <attribute name="new_contractlinedislikeid" />
    <attribute name="substituteproductid" />
    <attribute name="new_unit" />
    <attribute name="new_quantity />
    <attribute name="new_grouping" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="new_contractlineid" operator="eq"  value="{guid}" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

As shown above, both tables have a lookup (substituteproductid), which can be to the same product. In the case that the lookups are the same, I want to do a left join onto Table A. Basically, I want to return a single entitycollection from a single fetchXml string. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to use `link-entity`. This query should work for your scenario. [Referred the old discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48571969/7920473)

```
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' >
  <entity name= 'productsubstitute' >
    <attribute name='new_quantity' />
    <attribute name='new_unit' />
    <attribute name='new_grouping' />
    <filter type='and' >
      <condition attribute='productid' operator='eq' value= '{guid}' />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name='new_contractlinedislike' from='substitutedproductid' to='substituteproductid' link-type='outer' >
      <attribute name='new_contractlinedislikeid' />
      <attribute name= 'new_grouping' />
    <filter type='and' >
      <condition attribute='new_contractlineid' operator='eq' value= '{guid}' />
    </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun. I will test out the code asap. Another question, if I have two tables with 2 tables in between them, can I simply use nested link-entity to get the matching values?! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AlanJudi yes you can.

Comment: I'm assuming that I would have to add these attributes in between the link-entity tags

Comment: @AlanJudi exactly, I added an example

Comment: Hey Arun, I need your help with a question about powerBi, please go here: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Generate-Shipping-Labels-from-raw-table-in-PowerBi/td-p/587356

Comment: My custom visuals attempt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825079/properly-scale-and-position-rect-in-d3-js?noredirect=1#comment94501404_53825079